# Find the number of current members total in json file using javascript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I find the number of current members **total** json file "members"  using javascript (or jquery), given that "cccrEXP" is the club membership expiration date? Please note that a valid total of members ignores those with memberships that have expired.

## JSON

```
var members = 
[
{ "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "cccrEXP": "2018.10.10" },
{ "Name": "Attaya, James J", "cccrEXP": "2019.1.12" },
]
```

Comment: `members.length` ??

Comment: filter by now before cccrExp and take the length

Comment: No, some of the member's expiration dates are prior to today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter them by `cccrEXP` and get length property of the returned array

```js
var members = 
[
{ "Name": "Ahmed, Jamshed", "cccrEXP": "2018.10.10" },
{ "Name": "Attaya, James J", "cccrEXP": "2019.1.12" },
{ "Name": "George, Baily", "cccrEXP": "2018.1.12" },
];

var x = members.filter(o=> new Date(o.cccrEXP) >=new Date()).length;

console.log(x)
```